# iOS: Anybody gotten libtar or libarchive to build? (Problem with configure script.)

Tags: ios, configure

I'm having a problem building libraries that have a "configure" script, namely such scripts are not meant for compiling for iOS.

Is there a set of environment variables that I can set to induce "configure" to work for iOS?

I tried setting CC but that was not nearly enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Github project with static libraries and headers that build properly for iOS](https://github.com/davepeck/iOS-libarchive).

From the readme (Nov 2011):

> LibArchive Static Library for iOS Unfortunately, while
>   libarchive.dylib and libbz2.dylib are included in the iOS SDK, the
>   header files are not. This means that they are private APIs and cannot
>   be used if you intend to submit to the App Store.
>
> Never fear! This repository contains everything you need to build a
>   static version of libarchive for iOS. libbz2 is also included for
>   extra goodness.
>
> To keep naming of things sane, we build the library as libarc.a.
>
> For iOS 4.3+ copy the header files and library from the
>   build-for-iOS-4.3 directory into your project.
>
> For iOS 4.2 copy the header files and library from the
>   build-for-iOS-4.2 directory into your project.
>
> If you need to build this for an earlier version of iOS, you can
>   easily modify the build.sh script to point to whatever SDKs you like.
>   It should build fine on 3.x.
>
> TO GET IT FULLY LINKING you must also include libz.dylib in your list
>   of linked libraries. To do this in XCode 4, click on your project,
>   choose the Build Phases tab, go to Link Binary With Libraries, press
>   +, and choose libz.dylib from the (long) list of possible libraries to link against. This is because libarc.a links dynamically to libz.dylib
>   -- this is okay since, for whatever reason, AAPL saw fit to include the libz headers in the iOS SDK.
>
> The current libarchive version is 2.8.4. The bzlib2 version is 1.0.6.

Comment: I put together this static library many years ago and it's quite out of date now. I intend to update it to (1) use the latest lib archive 3, (2) compile with modern Xcode, (3) support 64-bit, and (4) have a cocoa pod in the near future, so please do take a look soon!

Comment: So how about the 64 bit version?